# Number of classes

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, svm

I'm applying the following code to my own data according to this tutorial http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/learning_curve.html

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.svm import SVC
train_sizes, train_scores, valid_scores = learning_curve(SVC(kernel='linear'), X, y, train_sizes=[50, 80, 110], cv=5)
```

However, I get the following error `ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1`

Here are my X and y:

`X.shape` `(2163, 8891)`

`y.shape` `(2163,)`

`type(X)`  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

`type(y)`  `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Using `print(set(y))` yields two classes `{'R', 'N'}`

Any thoughts on how to what is causing this error?

Comment: What are `X` and `y`?

Comment: I updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it happens due to cv = 5. Since you are using an integer, a simple K-Fold iterator will be used, which may split data in such a way that in a given training fold, only a single class is present.

Try using [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html) instead.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)
train_sizes, train_scores, valid_scores = learning_curve(SVC(kernel='linear'), 
                                                     X, y, 
                                                     train_sizes=[50, 80, 110], 
                                                     cv=skf)
```